# how to read lines terminating with a specific word into while loop

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a file in which there are some records and each record is split across multiple line.

**file.txt**

```
    <start some words
somewords
some words
some words"/>
    <start some words
some words
some words
some words"/>
```

Now i want to read record by record into my while loop and for that i have tried something like below

```
while IFS="/>" read line

code

done < file.txt
```

But it is reading only part of the record which is

```
<start some words
```

But i want to read record into line variable which is

```
     <start some words
somewords
some words
some words"/>
```

I have also tried something like below but it didn't work

```
sed -n '/<start/\/>/'p | while read line

code

done < file.txt
```

Can any one help me how to read data record wise?

Comment: Looks like xml.  Use a XML parser.

Comment: no it is not xml it is separate auditing file. Please help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do with those "records", it seems that you want to use `while read...` anyway. So the problem is how to convert multi-line record into single line.. I my understanding was right, check this awk:

```
 awk '/<start/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}' file
```

it will output:

```
<start some words somewords some words some words"/> 
<start some words2 some words2 some words2 some words2"/> 
<start some words3 some words3 some words3 some words3"/>
```

so that you could apply your logic in `code` on the line/record.

(the 2 and 3 were added by me, to distinguish which "record")

Comment: thanks and you understand my question perfectly and please let me know what this command is exactly doing ( step by step )

Comment: only two steps, @vidyadhar for each `<start ... />` block, `printf`, which will ignore the `newlines`, after the blocked was printed, print a newline.

Comment: If i understand correctly then you are taking data between starting and ending strings and printing and after every ending string printing a new line. isn't it?